# Width, height, res do not seem to affect configuration of exported plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, directory, jpeg

I am trying to export a plot from R-studio which should have a good enough quality for an academic paper - however, it just does not work to increase the size and quality of the exported plot!

Following data:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind("WBHO" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0), "SI" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0), "OORT" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0)))
```

I am using the following code for a prompt to choose the folder/location:

```
library(easycsv)
choose_dir = function(){
os = Identify.OS()
if(tolower(os) == "windows"){
directory <- utils::choose.dir()
}
if(tolower(os) == "macosx"){
system("osascript -e 'tell app \"RStudio\" to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt \"Choose Folder:\")' > /tmp/R_folder",
       intern = FALSE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
directory <- system("cat /tmp/R_folder && rm -f /tmp/R_folder", intern = TRUE)
}
return(directory)
}
folder = choose_dir()
```

Now, I am using the following code to create a barplot that is automatically saved under the folder I chose with the preceding code:

```
jpeg(sprintf("%s/%s.jpg", folder, "Means_Orientations", units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 300))
df %>%
gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>%
ggplot(aes(variable, value)) +
stat_summary(geom="bar", fun.y="mean", color = "brown") +
coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) +
expand_limits(y = c(0, 7)) +
labs(x = "", y = "") +
theme(text = element_text(size = 20), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F2F0ED"))
dev.off()
```

As you can see, I have added specification concerning units, width, height and res - however, the plot just stays the same, no changes at all! I assume that it has to do with the "sprintf" command I am using - but I don't know how to fix this problem.
Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [`ggsave`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html) instead?

Comment: Hei! If I do the following: ggsave("%s/%s.jpg", folder, "Means_Orientations", units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 300)
dev.off()  I get an error prompt

Comment: I don't know what your error is, but you don't need `dev.off()` with `ggsave`.

Comment: even after deleting dev.off() I get the error prompt: "Unknown graphics device 'Means_Orientations'" which refers to the name I want to give the file. It seems the way I enter the folder and the name is not supported by ggsave.

Comment: seems to work like this: ggsave(sprintf("%s/%s.jpg", folder, "Means_OrientationsW", units = "in", width = 5, height = 5, res = 300)) - I did not include "sprintf" before. Can you tell me why it does not work with jpeg() and dev.off() ??